# Deeplinking not working in flutter ios build but working fine in android

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, deep-linking

done all required configuration like
apple-app-site-association file hosted
added associated domains in the entitlement file.
Entitlement file is added in the target bundle resources.
what could be the problem?